# Drupal and PHP 5.3

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is Drupal perfectly working on PHP 5.3 ?

I tried some modules and received several warnings.. is it going to take some months before it will be completely optimized ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated here --> [Drupal Requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements)

> PHP 5.3 is not yet supported by Drupal 5.x, but is supported by Drupal 6.14 core and higher (see the release notes for 6.14) and also by Drupal 7.x. Note that some contributed modules may not be compatible with PHP 5.3, and that some PHP 5.3 configurations still show warnings with Drupal 6.14; work is ongoing to resolve the latter in [#360605: PHP 5.3 Compatibility](http://drupal.org/node/360605).

Thus in theory from drupal 6.14+ all core modules are compatible with php 5.3, therefore your warnings could likely come from some contributed modules. I suggest you to update all modules to the latest version, and if you still have troubles, to have a look in the issue queues of your modules.

Additionally, I suggest you to have a look at the link: [#360605: PHP 5.3 Compatibility](http://drupal.org/node/360605) to check if some of your problems are the same...

Comment: hi, one more thing: let's say the hosting service is going to upgrade its php libraries in the future. My customer needs to contact me again to upgrade Drupal, right ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the customer could need your help (I really doubt he could manage PHP warnings or similar troubles if they appear). But I hope drupal 7 will be released soon, so maybe at that time you could directly upgrade to the new major version, and gain compatibility for a greater amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Loads of contrib does not support PHP 5.3 yet. The answer (if you can) is provide and test patches to help the maintainers get their code up to speed. Unfortunately, core being 5.3 ready doesn't really matter when so much of contrib is not. It will change. OS-X and most popular Linux desktop distros now ship with PHP 5.3, as do nearly all the Windows quick-start WAMP packages, so contrib will be forced to get up to date in the next few months. I'm sure all Drupal 7 contrib will be 5.3 safe too.

Comment: hi, one more thing: let's say the hosting service is going to upgrade its php libraries in the future. My customer needs to contact me again to upgrade Drupal, right ?